# How to have PHP display errors? (I've added ini_set and error_reporting, but just gives 500 on errors)

Tags: php, html, debugging

So, I don't really have any errors in my current web page, but I want to be able to see an error when they pop up, instead of the HTTP 500 error page. I googled around a bit and thought adding these two lines would fix everything.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

NOTE: I don't have access to the php.ini file, as I'm using my school account's server.

So I introduced a bug (no semicolon after $buggy) like so at the top of my page:

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$buggy

$x = 4 + 2;
...
```

However, I just get a Server error:

"The website encountered an error while retrieving http://mywebpage.com/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly."

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I've reconfigured my code:

```
<?php 
include_once 'database/errorSettings.php';
?>
<?php 

$buggy // whoops
$x = 4 + 2;
...
```

errorSettings.php is the following:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

But it still doesn't work... wrong way to reconfigure?

Comment: Do you have an error redirect in your .htaccess file?

Comment: you seem to be confusing Apache errors with php.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. I don't think I have access to the .htaccess file, but maybe I do let me check. Also, don't know if this is relevant, but the only bug in the page is the missing semicolon. If I take it out, the page loads fine. (checking to see if I can find said .htaccess file)

Comment: @Dagon: So, are you saying that I can't display php syntax/other errors by setting the error_reporting settings like given above...? I'm just trying to understand how to print out PHP errors given that I can't access the php.ini or do much server administration

Comment: @Dagon And you seem to be confusing what's causing HTTP 500 errors. If the PHP script fails and doesn't catch its own error and doesn't produce any alternative output, Apache will resort to the only reasonable thing: a 500 error.

Comment: i know this, and how will editing php.ini help? it wont - op is confusing the two.

Comment: @Dagon It would help in that it would default PHP to display errors, which means the PHP script would produce output which means Apache would not throw up its own 500 page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you have is a parse error. Those are thrown before any code is executed. A PHP file needs to be parsed in its entirety before any code in it can be executed. If there's a parse error in the file where you're setting your error levels, they won't have taken effect by the time the error is thrown.

Either break your files up into smaller parts, like setting the error levels in one file and then `include`ing another file which contains the actual code (and errors), or set the error levels outside PHP using php.ini or .htaccess directives.

Comment: Alright, I've reconfigured my code as above (in my edit), but it doesn't seem to work. I'm going to give it another go.

Comment: The file that sets the error settings needs to run successfully first. If the parse error is in the file that includes the file that sets the error settings, that doesn't help.

Comment: Or use an IDE like Eclipse which will show you parse errors in red

Answer (score 13):

You need to set the error_reporting value in a .htaccess file. Since there is a parse error, it never runs the error_reporting() function in your PHP code.

Try this in a .htaccess file (assuming you can use one):

```
php_flag display_errors 1
php_value error_reporting 30719
```

I think 30719 corresponds to E_ALL but I may be wrong.

**Edit Update:** http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

```
int error_reporting ([ int $level ] )
---
32767   E_ALL (integer)     
All errors and warnings, as supported, except of   level E_STRICT prior to PHP 5.4.0.   32767 in PHP 5.4.x, 30719 in PHP 5.3.x, 6143 in PHP   5.2.x, 2047 previously
```

Comment: Doesn't look like I have access to the .htaccess file :(

Comment: Note: in some cases (such as missing functions under funky circumstances) you may also need to enable `display_startup_errors`

Comment: Yes, display_startup_errors should be `on`/`1`. Also, I put an level explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to what deceze said above. This is a parse error, so in order to debug a parse error, create a new file in the root named debugSyntax.php. Put this in it:

```
<?php

///////    SYNTAX ERROR CHECK    ////////////
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

//replace "pageToTest.php" with the file path that you want to test. 
include('pageToTest.php'); 

?>
```

Run the debugSyntax.php page and it will display parse errors from the page that you chose to test.

Comment: Just for the next noob ...  The above wont be necessry if you have access to the apache error log where a simple ( linux environment ) 'tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log'  will show you what errors you have in your php script including parse errors

Answer (score 2):

Just write a following code on top of PHP file:

```
ini_set('display_errors','on');
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax errors is not checked easily in external servers, just runtime errors.

What I do?  Just like you, I use

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

However, before run I check syntax errors in a PHP file using an online PHP syntax checker.

The best, IMHO is [PHP Code Checker](https://phpcodechecker.com/index.htm)

I copy all the source code, paste inside the main box and click the `Analyze` button.

It is not the most practical method, but the 2 procedures are complementary and it solves the problem completely

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem when using PHP5.4 and Plesk 11.5

Somehow, the error reporting and display error settings in the Plesk domain configuration page were completely overriding any local settings in .htaccess or the PHP scripts. I have not found a way to prevent this happening, so use the Plesk settings to turn error reporting on and off.

You may have settings in your php.ini that prevents the local site from overriding these settings, perhaps enforced by the control panel used on your server.

Answer (score 0):

To people using Codeigniter (i'm on C3):

The index.php file overwrite php.ini configuration, so on index.php file, line 68:

```
case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    break;
```

You can change this option to set what you need. Here's the complete list:

```
1   E_ERROR
2   E_WARNING
4   E_PARSE
8   E_NOTICE
16  E_CORE_ERROR
32  E_CORE_WARNING
64  E_COMPILE_ERROR
128 E_COMPILE_WARNING
256 E_USER_ERROR
512 E_USER_WARNING
1024    E_USER_NOTICE
6143    E_ALL
2048    E_STRICT
4096    E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR
```

Hope it helps.