# PHP does not save HTML code to database

Tags: php, mysql

PHP 5.4 (recommended by my host)
MySQL 5
*I have no logs.*

I have a script that was working perfectly fine a week ago. I've made absolutely **ZERO** changes to it at all. It's a simple news system script.

It use to allow saving with html text such as bold, italics, underline etc. When editing the news it would display it the same way it was saved. The only thing that changed was the 
. It would be added before saving to the database but removed when displayed.

This is the portion of the script that saves the information. I took out any information that was not valid to the question. Only displaying the content containing the issue.

```
<?php require('check.php'); 
require_once('settings.php');

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

    $id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['id']));
    $month = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['month']));
    $date = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['date']));
    $year = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['year']));
    $time = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['time']));
    $entry = $_POST['entry'];
    $avatar = $_POST['avatar'];
    $title = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['title']));

/*    $entry = nl2br($entry); */
    $entry = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r/", "<br />", $entry);

    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $title = addslashes($title);
        $entry = addslashes($entry);
    }

    $timestamp = strtotime ($month . " " . $date . " " . $year . " " . $time);

    $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "UPDATE my_blog SET timestamp='$timestamp', title='$title', entry='$entry', avatar='$avatar' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1") or print ("Can't update entry.<br />" . ((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));

    header("Location: ../entry.php?id=" . $id);

}

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $id = (int)$_POST['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "DELETE FROM my_blog WHERE id='$id'") or print ("<p class=\"error\"Can't delete entry.<br />" . ((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)) . "</p>");
    if ($result != false) {
        print "<p class=\"success\">The entry has been successfully deleted from the database.</p>";
        exit;
    }
}

if (!isset($_GET['id']) || empty($_GET['id']) || !is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    die("Invalid entry ID.");
}
else {
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
}

require_once("header.php");
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM my_blog WHERE id='$id'") or print ("Can't select entry.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . ((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $old_timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
    $old_title = stripslashes($row['title']);
    $old_entry = nl2br($row['entry']);
    $old_avatar = stripslashes($row['avatar']);
    $old_password = $row['password'];

    $old_title = str_replace('"','\'',$old_title);
    $old_entry = str_replace('\r\n', '<br />', $old_entry);

    $old_month = date("F",$old_timestamp);
    $old_date = date("d",$old_timestamp);
    $old_year = date("Y",$old_timestamp);
    $old_time = date("H:i",$old_timestamp);
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<p><input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<b><label for="month">Date:</label></b>
<table width=100%> 
<tr>
<td width="25%"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="date" id="date" size="2" value="<?php echo $old_date; ?>" /></td>
<td width="50%"><select class="form-control" name="month" id="month">
<option value="<?php echo $old_month; ?>"><?php echo $old_month; ?></option>
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
<option value="March">March</option>
<option value="April">April</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">June</option>
<option value="July">July</option>
<option value="August">August</option>
<option value="September">September</option>
<option value="October">October</option>
<option value="November">November</option>
<option value="December">December</option>
</select></td>
<td width="25%"><select class="form-control" name="year" id="year">
<option value="<?php echo $old_year; ?>"><?php echo $old_year; ?></option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b><label for="time">Time:</label></b></td>
<td><b><label for="title">Title:</label></b></td>
<td><b><label for="avatar">Icon:</label></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="time" id="time" size="5" value="<?php echo $old_time; ?>" /></td>
<td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<?php echo $old_title; ?>" size="40" /></td>
<td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="avatar" id="avatar" size="40" maxlength="100" value="<?php echo $old_avatar; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p><textarea class="form-control" cols="80" rows="20" name="entry" id="entry"><?php echo $old_entry; ?></textarea></p>
<p><button type="submit" name="update" id="update" class="btn btn-default">Update!</button></p>
</form>
<p><strong>Before deleting, be absolutely sure - there is no confirmation nor is there any way to reverse deletion!</strong><br />
<small>(You may be shown your entry again after deleting - do not worry, it HAS been deleted.  Check the main page of the blog if you are still unsure.</small></p>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<button type="submit" name="delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-default">Yes, I am absolutely and positively sure I want to delete this entry.</button>
</form>

<?php
require_once("footer.php");
((is_null($___mysqli_res = mysqli_close($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]))) ? false : $___mysqli_res);
?>
```

I've tried to see if this was a host issue but apparently many people across many host that use this specific script are having this issue. It all started at the exact same time for everyone. But not one person has a clue what is going on. Everyone is running at least on PHP 5.4 nothing older.

It's just really strange how something that was working stopped working and was looking for some insight on what could be the issue. Google has been of no help and I can't find anything here on stack overflow.

Please note that I have tried changing the way of saving the information. I know using nl2br() should actually not be used to save information to the database only to display information from the datasbase. But I did not write the script and it is no longer being kept by the original developer of the script.

**I've converted everything to mysqli_ with no changes to the problem.**

settings.php

```
<?php
    $users = array($user => md5($pass));
    $salt = substr(md5(date("F")), 8);
    $cards_seperate_directory = FALSE;

    $connect = mysql_connect("$db_server", "$db_user", "$db_password")
        or die( DATABASE_CONNECT_ERROR . mysql_error() );
    mysql_select_db("$db_database", $connect)
        or die( DATABASE_CONNECT_ERROR . mysql_error() );

    function CleanUp($data) {
        $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
        return $data;
        }

    function escape_sql($sql) {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $sql = stripslashes($sql);
        return mysql_real_escape_string($sql);
        }
?>
```

Comment: Can you post more of the code to show where all of the variables are set? It would be useful to see $timestamp, $title, $avatar, and $id.

Comment: 1. HTML cannot store anything into a DB, as it is a markup language, not a programming language; 2. If nobody didn't changed anything, it would still work – ergo, someone MUST have changed something; 3. “not working” is not a sufficent problem description to get you helped here

Comment: Sounds like PHP was upgraded and the `mysql_*` functions went away. Any errors? Check the logs? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of `addslashes`.

Comment: tips: Don't use nl2br before the query, use it when you actually need html. This way you can still expose the non-html version on your site. Also, look into mysqli, as mysql is depricated.

Comment: @feeela of course, it means the HTML is not being stored, not that html doesn't store it ;)

Comment: Hi, try printing everything you're passing to mysql_query and then run the query manually. Maybe this gives you a hint.

Comment: @thirtyish - $timestamp, $title, $avatar, and $id all look like the following $id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['id']));

Comment: Have you made any debugging attempts at all to see what is going wrong?

Comment: @JayBlanchard - I thought it could be that everything has switched over from mysql_ to mysqli_ just haven't tried to test it yet.

Comment: @panther I've tried changing it from addslashes to mysql_real_escape_string absolutely no changes.

Comment: @RenePot If you actually read my post you would have read the part where I said I know I'm not suppose to use nl2br. But I didn't write the script.

Comment: @VianelisNinaMartinez could you edit your question and add the relevant parts of the code so we can see more of it?

Comment: @MikeBrant yes I've tried debugging it. Thats why I know the issue is with nl2br() and the magic_quotes_gpc() specifically.

Comment: @thirtyish I'll just add the entire page.

Comment: You say you've made no changes to the script. But has anything changed in check.php or settings.php? Can you check those?

Comment: @feeela - i'm speaking about the actual code it's self such as <b>text here</b>. I've done it many times before without any issues.

Comment: @thirtyish - nothing has been changed to the check.php or settings.php. Check.php is just a page to check if I have permission to access the page when logged in. The settings.php only contains the connection to the database.

Comment: The main issue in my comment was that something must have changed if something suddenly stops working and that it is your responsibility to gather enough information on the issue. I don't have crystal ball and can't tell you what wnet wrong with some script I never saw and wihtout knowing the circumstances under which it ran and under which it does not…

Comment: @feeela - well if you read the post I said absolutely no changes were made other then when I tried to fix the issue. As well as other people from other websites have the exact same script with the exact same issue. You can not duplicate and issue across multiple website's at the exact same time without all making the exact same change. Seeing as the original developer of the script no longer keeps it updated we can safely assume there was no recent update released for it. I mean it's called process of elimination. Let's use some of our brains here. I gave all the information I have.

Comment: I do not talk about updating that script. I guess that there was a server update. You still do not provide debug and error log outputs. If you do not know how get these infos, you should hire a profiessional to do so for you.

Comment: BTW: »Let's use some of our brains here.« Please repeat that in front of a mirror…

Comment: if you've converted everything to MySQLi can you update your code on the question, please. @VianelisNinaMartinez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Improved Version:

Please note: All functions referencing magic quotes really shouldn't be needed and should be removed. I have used the data from the settings.php to set up the `$dbLink` which is the database link required for MySQLi.

I have also set the error logging to appear in your "tmp/php-error.log" this will **NOT** be in your web directory but will be below your web directory and accessible by FTP. I can't set a better location as I dont know the structure of your hosting, but feel free to edit.

Where you aware that your settings.php mysql_connect was NOT MySQLi? 
The code below should run and should give you any error outputs including notices and warnings to the file specified. Upload this and see how it runs.

Also not that on your original code there was some require and jazz at the bottom of the HTML content, you don't need that, for this debugging.

I strongly advise against that automatic MySQLi converter.

Let me know how this goes....

```
require('check.php');
//require_once('settings.php');

$users = array($user => md5($pass));
$salt = substr(md5(date("F")), 8);
$cards_seperate_directory = FALSE;

$dbLink = mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_password, $db_database);


error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $id = strip_tags($_POST['id']);
    $id = htmlspecialchars($id);
    $month = strip_tags($_POST['month']);
    $month = htmlspecialchars($month);
    $date = strip_tags($_POST['date']);
    $date = htmlspecialchars($date);
    $year = strip_tags($_POST['year']);
    $year = htmlspecialchars($year);
    $time = strip_tags($_POST['time']);
    $time = htmlspecialchars($time);

    $avatar = $_POST['avatar'];
    $title = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($title);

    $entry = $_POST['entry'];
    /*    $entry = nl2br($entry); */
    $entry = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r/", "<br />", $entry);

    $timestamp = strtotime ($month . " " . $date . " " . $year . " " . $time);

    $result = mysqli_query( $dbLink, "UPDATE my_blog SET timestamp='$timestamp', title='$title', entry='$entry',
avatar='$avatar' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($dbLink));

    header("Location: ../entry.php?id=" . $id);
    die();
}

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $id = (int)$_POST['id']; //assumes the ID is an int.
    if ($id > 0 ) {
        $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, "DELETE FROM my_blog WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1 ") or die(mysqli_error($dbLink));
        if ($result !== false) {
            print "<p class='success'>The entry has been successfully deleted from the database.</p>";
            die();
        }
    }
}

if (!isset($_GET['id']) || empty($_GET['id']) || !is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    die("Invalid entry ID.");
}
else {
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
}

require_once("header.php");
$result = mysqli_query($dbLink, "SELECT * FROM my_blog WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($dbLink));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $old_timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
    $old_title = stripslashes($row['title']);
    $old_entry = nl2br($row['entry']);
    $old_avatar = stripslashes($row['avatar']);
    $old_password = $row['password'];

    $old_title = str_replace('"','\'',$old_title);
    $old_entry = str_replace('\r\n', '<br />', $old_entry);

    $old_month = date("F",$old_timestamp);
    $old_date = date("d",$old_timestamp);
    $old_year = date("Y",$old_timestamp);
    $old_time = date("H:i",$old_timestamp);
}
?>

(rest of file)
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually after I posted the settings section to you I noticed it was still in mysql not mysqli. Will upload and see how it runs.

Comment: as long as you can access whatever directory the error log is set to, that should give the best indicator as to where the problem lies

Comment: Well one portion of the problem has been fixed. When the information displays in the textbox its displaying correctly. But it's still missing my html tags. Such as <b></b> around my text. Still can't find my logs. I've never had this issue before. I use to use iPage for hosting my site's and always found my logs with no issue. I'm currently on DreamHost and the directory is still empty.

Comment: if you're sure you're in the correct folder - as in if your website is in [base]/home/www/ then the /tmp/ folder is in `[base]/home/tmp/`. Ask your hosting provider for help in this case. And the HTML tags, do they show up in the MySQL database? Do they show up on the source of your HTML file? `<` and `>` tags are removed by default from textareas. You need to check that your `$old_entry` actual value is correct and then run `$old_entry` through a `htmlspecialchars()` function. Also `<b>` is deprecated, use `<strong>` .

Comment: The tags are not being saved at all in the MySQL database. (I use both <b> & <strong> for styling purposes. I use strong for bolding important things in red. While <b> for just style.) I do have access to my log folder. That's not an issue. The /home/tmp/ folder exist. I can get to it. But inside there are no files at all.

Comment: ask your hosting provider about your error logging. As for the Original Problem: see my update

Comment: I've been looking at this too long and am loosing my focus (I started looking into form encoding types but I think that's a very unlikely cause). I think you should do some `var_dump`s along the information route to establish at what point the data changes. as in, as soon as you open your file, `var_dump($_POST['entry'])` and view source and you should see your HTML tags, then do the same var_dump just the line before you write to the database, see what's changed. Let me know if anything turns up and I'll look back later

Comment: The more I look at it the less I see what would be causing changes to the `'entry'` value. Try this: change the name to something else, change the variable in PHP to something else again, and comment out or otherwise remove your `cleanUp` function in settings.php. If there are NO other files or code that effects the code then we can close that option of error. Then we can see what's going on, with an update . . .

Comment: @VianelisMartinez the following link will give you some good help on sorting out error reporting, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083533/how-to-have-php-display-errors-ive-added-ini-set-and-error-reporting-but-jus one indicator I didn't think of was that errors will not be reported if there is a parse error on the page - but I assume the page does run ok, just gives upexpected results. Anyhow, give it a read.

Comment: Yes the pages are running fine. So there are technically no errors. That would explain my lack of error logs. I'm going to try doing what you suggested above in just a second.

Comment: You are awesome. I changed it from entry to post and it works!!! XD let's see if this works for everyone else having the issue.

Comment: I specifically said to you to create a deliberate error to ensure the error logs worked ok *sigh* . Ok, Unless something is happening in the check.php file I don't see what is causing the lack of HTML code appearing in your saved data.

Comment: well that's good news. If you could be kind enough to tick my answer and mark me up that would be great. Although I'm curious why a certain `name` causes the error, and if this is your code or the d/l'ed code that generates this . . . . i'm sure there's cross referencing or something going on here. But glad it's fixed for you :)

Comment: oh yes you did tell me to create an error. gah sorry. I got distracted and forgot to do that part. I just tried it though and I still am not getting any logs. It's weird. I will contact my host about this. I'm just as surprised that this was the issue. Which now makes sense why so many other people across the internet that use the script are also having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

### *Possible issues*:

php has been updated by your server, which can often result in nested functionality breaking with large step upgrades. I found that with `strip_tags()` this happened to me last year.

As stated by Jay in the comments, do some standard PHP error checking, read your error logs file. PHP has an excellent error output system and *will* show you what's wrong, even if not showing you how to fix it.

Email your server hosts and specifically and categorically ask them if they've done updates and changes to the system, this includes things like updates to your `php.ini` file which can effect a lot of changes. They **should** always inform you when updating stuff but sometimes they don't.

I find it hard to see that this is a wide internet based issue with competent programmers if it is still on code that is five years out of date (MySQL) .

The whole `magic quotes` is something that is long deprecated and maybe actually deleted functionality(?). Magic quotes is a very poor practise to use, so much so I think it was removed in PHP5. Avoid it with extreme prejudice.

Do not get angry at people trying to help you here. Please. I know, I do really know it's frustrating when stuff doesn't work, but telling someone who is taking time out to advise and help you to "use your brain" when ***they can only go on as much information as you provide*** is rude and will not encourage others to assist you.

So, routes to solve your issue:

1) read your comments from Jay stating about setting up PHP error reporting and then rerun the script, then establish the error log is being generated (with deliberate errors) and then download the log and read it, it will give you a valuable insight into where the issue is.

2) Update to MySQLi. Do this as soon as practically possible. It will not effect / damage the working of your scripts but will improve them better.

3) Get in touch with your server hosts and get some specific clarification as to what and if things have been updated

4) Check all of your files from a historic GIT or similar depository, as your code is very poorly written and I'm sure you'll have security flaws aplenty, so there is a possibility some malware or hack could (possibly) compromised you.

5) Hold your tongue, don't bite the people that take time to assist you.

6) Feedback, update your question with the new information: what version of PHP are you running, what version of MySQL are you running, what does your Error log say? Have you read over http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php for possible issues, including in the comments?

7) we can then give you better and clearer more helpful solutions

## *Updated issues:*

```
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "UPDATE my_blog SET timestamp='$timestamp', title='$title', entry='$entry', avatar='$avatar' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1") or print ("Can't update entry.<br />" . ((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));
```

This row has a pile of what look like poorly implemented PHP Globals but these are really old and deprecated as well, with PHP 5.4 you say you have, these globals are useless and not to be used.

What made you put `$GLOBALS` into your MySQL? Where do these varaibles appear and why are they written in such a poor syntax. These will NOT help your cause.

Comment: "MySQL is upgraded to MySQLi" is not entirely correct. The database package is called MySQL and that hasn't changed. It's the PHP function call `mysql_query` that is being deprecated. A modern interface like `mysqli` or PDO is a good alternative.

Comment: I mean that for example on my current server any php action with Mysql_ fails, but Mysqli_ works, although I realise I may have phrased that poorly

Comment: I'm just trying to avoid confusion here between MySQL the database and `mysql_query` the PHP function. Some people seem to think they're the same thing. Also worth noting that "magic quotes", which was one of the worst ideas in the history of bad ideas, has been permanently removed from all recent versions of PHP. Any code testing for that is highly suspicious.

Comment: fair enough. I've removed that text anyway as the OP states they have updated everything to MySQLi, personally I think PHP error logs will hold the solution. . . .

Comment: I never use magic quotes (as it's bad practise) so I wasn't sure of its current status but hoped it would be long gone... I will update my answer

Comment: Actually thank you for the response. I'm seriously not lying when I tell you it's a wide internet base issue. I even at first thought that was impossible and thought the issue was only on my end. But it's just this specific script causing issues. Like I stated before I didn't write this script. It's not mine at all. But the original owner of the script is not around the update/edit/fix it. Will edit original post with my current version of php etc.

Comment: @VianelisMartinez saying that you have no logs is incorrect. You do have logs, you can't find them. please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834583/where-can-i-find-error-log-files which is a guide for generating and outputting PHP logs. Also follow the advise of Jay on your question comments, thanks :)

Comment: @Martin - I'll take a look. I've checked my log folder and to my surprise its completely empty. I then went to my control panel and my logs there were also not there. Will update in a few mins.

Comment: @Martin - To be honest I used a master converter to convert from mysql_ to mysqli_ I did not manually update this.

Comment: I've never heard of a master converter, and by the looks of it, it's not upto date at all, or it uses very non-standard syntaxing that is very unwise for situations where other people need to read your code. If you can edit your question and add the contents of the settings.php file I will rewrite your whole code and put it out as a new answer, then you can run it and get some error results, because I really, really doubt the current format of MySQLi will run as intended.  Cheers

Comment: I actually found it here on stack overflow. But the converter is over at GitHub. It actually converted my settings page also. Everything is still working as normal. Except the script I'm having a problem with. I'm still having a problem with. Everything else is completely fine. Yes I just realized it is outdated as well. I did not realize this before until you mentioned it.

Comment: if you can show me the settings.php file I am working through bringing your code up to standard. I will also add error logging for you.

Comment: @Martin - I'll add it to the end of the original post. Please note my mysql login information will be missing.