# Youtube API V3 PHP Search by Keyword code sample not working

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I tried running the sample code that Google gives you on their developer Code Sample page (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#search_by_keyword) isn't working for me. I made sure to download the latest version of the library from GitHub, installed it to my PHP5/Apache2 server, changed the Include Path, and for some reason, one of the require_once items is not working properly. Here is the code that I have (modified only with some echo statements). I put in my developer key, but have removed it in this post for obvious reasons.

```
<?php
$htmlBody = <<<END
<form method="GET">
  <div>
    Search Term: <input type="search" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Enter Search Term">
  </div>
  <div>
    Max Results: <input type="number" id="maxResults" name="maxResults" min="1" max="50" step="1" value="25">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
END;

// This code will execute if the user entered a search query in the form
// and submitted the form. Otherwise, the page displays the form above.
if ($_GET['q'] && $_GET['maxResults']) {
    echo "echo 1";
    echo "<br/>";
  // Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/home/pi/google-api-php-client/src');
    require_once('Google/Client.php');
    echo "echo 2<br/>";
    require_once ('Google/Service/YouTube.php');
    echo "echo 3";
    echo "<br/>";

  /*
   * Set $DEVELOPER_KEY to the "API key" value from the "Access" tab of the
   * Google Developers Console <https://console.developers.google.com/>
   * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
   */
  $DEVELOPER_KEY = 'my-api-key-here';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);

  // Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
  $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

  try {
    // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
    // query term.
    $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
      'q' => $_GET['q'],
      'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
    ));

    $videos = '';
    $channels = '';
    $playlists = '';

    // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
    // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
    foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
      switch ($searchResult['id']['kind']) {
        case 'youtube#video':
          $videos .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
              $searchResult['snippet']['title'], $searchResult['id']['videoId']);
          break;
        case 'youtube#channel':
          $channels .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
              $searchResult['snippet']['title'], $searchResult['id']['channelId']);
          break;
        case 'youtube#playlist':
          $playlists .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
              $searchResult['snippet']['title'], $searchResult['id']['playlistId']);
          break;
      }
    }

    $htmlBody .= <<<END
    <h3>Videos</h3>
    <ul>$videos</ul>
    <h3>Channels</h3>
    <ul>$channels</ul>
    <h3>Playlists</h3>
    <ul>$playlists</ul>
END;
  } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>YouTube Search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?=$htmlBody?>
  </body>
</html>
```

with the interesting part being here

```
    echo "echo 1";
    echo "<br/>";
  // Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/home/pi/google-api-php-client/src');
    require_once('Google/Client.php');
    echo "echo 2<br/>";
    require_once ('Google/Service/YouTube.php');
    echo "echo 3";
    echo "<br/>";
```

When I run the page, the output is this

```
echo 1
echo 2
```

What's happening with the second require_once statement that causes the page to stop running after that? At one point I had an echo statement immediately following the set_include_path(), but that seemed to be working properly, so I removed it.

I solved the issue by adding all dependencies manually. After adding all required dependencies, this is what I ended up with.

```
require_once ('Google/Logger/Null.php');
require_once('Google/Client.php');
require_once ('Google/Config.php');
require_once ('Google/Model.php');
require_once ('Google/Collection.php');
require_once ('Google/Service.php');
require_once ('Google/Service/Resource.php');
require_once ('Google/Service/YouTube.php');
```

Comment: check the error log. File might not be present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```
require_once 'include/Google/autoload.php';
```

in front of code, and delete all other require like:

```
//require_once 'include/Google/Client.php'; 
//require_once 'include/Google/Service/YouTube.php';
```

But the php version should greater than 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Some things you can try:

- Turn on PHP's error output. If an error occurs, you get an information in the resulting html. You can find more information on how to enable it in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083533/how-to-have-php-display-errors-ive-added-ini-set-and-error-reporting-but-jus).
- Make sure `Google/Service/YouTube.php` exists. Navigate to the folder and check manually.
- Print the include path before including `YouTube.php` (I don't actually think this could be the problem, but who knows...)

Comment: Added error reporting, I get the following error.

    `Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service' not found in /home/pi/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/YouTube.php on line 32`

Comment: That sounds like some dependency is missing. I don't think so, but have you made any changes to the library source code?

Comment: I added `require_once ('Google/Service.php');` and the error changed to `Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service_Resource' not found in /home/pi/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/YouTube.php on line 1332`

Comment: As I keep adding dependecies, more keep missing. Is there something I'm missing that loads the ones it needs automatically, or will I have to keep searching manually?

Comment: I just downloaded the library to reproduce the problem and I got it too. Either we are both totally daft, or Google have some strange bugs in their code.

Comment: I see there is an Autoloader function included, but no instructions on how to use. Quick google search yielded nothing helpful. I solved the problem, but I ended up adding all dependencies manually. I've edited the main post to include my list of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't set your PHP's include path correctly. If you add this client library's src/ file into include path, it should just work fine.